# How to apply multiple functions to a single, common parameter?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

How can I apply multiple functions, each producing a single map, to a common parameter, then merge all results? Can this be improved?

```
(merge {} (podr root) (version root) (year root) (month root))
```

where `root` is the common argument and `podr`, `version`, `year` and `month` are the functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a seq of functions and use `map` to apply each one to `root`:

```
(into {} (map #(% root) [podr version year month]))
```

Or, you can use `juxt` to achieve the same:

```
(into {} ((juxt podr version year month) root))
```

Both are more or less equal.

Answer (score 0):

Map application over a list of functions.

E.g. in Haskell it would be:

```
> map (\f -> f 2) [(+1), (*2), (^3)]
[3,4,8]
```

Or, using `($)` as `f $ x = f x` you can apply :

```
> map ($ 2) [(+1), (*2), (^3)]
[3,4,8]
```

Same approach in any language with first class functions and application.